# call to C and c++ both in a single java program

Tags: java, c++, c

hi all is it possible to declare to native methods in java so that one method is defined in c and other method is defined in c++.m getting confusion in it . please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As long as the interface uses the standard C calling convention, Java doesn't really care in which language it's implemented. That means you have to surround the declarations in an `extern "C"` block if you happen to be writing C++:

```
#include <jni.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT jstring MyNativeMethod(JNIEnv *, jobject);
}
#endif
```

It's up to you whether to implement `MyNativeMethod` in C, C++ or any other language.

Of course, this is already done for you in the header file generated by `javah`, `extern "C"` and all.